# Folder to a mounted media device issue: target is not a directory

Tags: directory, cp

I’m installing GitLab using this command

```shell
sudo cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /path/to/mount
```

and it is throwing this error:

```
cp: target '/path/to/mount' is not a directory
```

What is the problem?

Comment: So, is `/path/to/mount` a directory or not? What does `ls -ld /path/to/mount` output?